# Vlookup is not working fails with N/A return despite i have value

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, vlookup

My Vlookup function isn't working, it fails with `N/A` despite the fact that I have values. Have a look in screenshots how can i solve it

[image]

[See File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YO2aOUt8aPYPRnlGw63eAyy_Y5VbOGdh1Pm7orhvExg/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

VLOOKUP looks up the value (J12) from the **first** column in the lookup range. You are trying to lookup *689* in B6:B16 which is a collection of names.

You need an INDEX/MATCH pair to retrieve the *name* from column B after matching *689* in column C.

```
=INDEX(B:B, MATCH(J12, C:C, 0))
```

That will return the name on an exact match; i.e. *689* in J12 matches *689* in C9 and returns *Messi* from B9.

If you want an approximate match, the numerical values in column C need to be in either ascending or descending order. Your original VLOOKUP defaults to an ascending order approximate match so it wasn't going to work reliably in any event.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a  workaround way to use VLOOKUP doing the Left Lookup,

In `J13`, enter formula :

```
=VLOOKUP(I13,IF({1,0},G5:G15,C5:C15),2,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/vlookup.html

Exact Match
Most of the time you are looking for an exact match when you use the VLOOKUP function in Excel. Let's take a look at the arguments of the VLOOKUP function.USE this link check
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MfhWzInBWeFg76MJ-iQaFBfhSdyOx241

change no value

[image]